# Visual Studio 2008 - Add Component from Source Code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, components

I want to add a component to the toolbox so that I can drag and drop it onto my windows form. I know I can add items to the toolbox by right-clicking and going to "Choose items", but what if I only have the source code for the component? How do I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the source code to build the component and then add it as you described.

Per comment: I'm not able to repro your problem.  If the project is in the same solution as the winform project, it should appear in the toolbox automatically and be draggable to the form.  But, even when I use the Browse ... feature in the [Choose Items dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyca0t6t(VS.80).aspx) I am able to add the component and then drag it to the form without error.  What is the error you see precisely?

Comment: Ah...right... build the project. I guess that makes sense. *face palm*

Comment: Says it can't find the library when I try to drop it onto my form now. Place it in a searchable path... place what exactly? I have a DLL that it generates, but putting that in system32 doesn't help.

Comment: It's ScintillaNET I'm trying to get working: http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx#DownloadLatest
Didn't have any luck with the MSI, so I'm trying source. Error = Failed to create component 'Scintilla'. System.IO.FileNotFoundException. blah blah blah... Please place the library in a searchable path.... not found at ScintillaNet.Scintilla.get_CreateParams().